# Select children under the css pseudo class selector

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using Bootstrap tabs, both directly under `<body>`, and inside a `.modal`. I need to select the tabs not inside a `.modal` via `css`. But this doesn't work:

```
var act = $("div:not(.modal) ul.nav li";
```

Intead of disregarding `.modal` contents, it also selects the tabs inside `.modal`s. Is this a known limitation, is this achievable? Is there any workaround for this?

```
<body>
    <div>
        ...
        <!--  More nested on actual code-->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="modal fade lookup" id="search-adjustment-report-header-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I actually need this query for setting some cookies, default tab selected, etc.

Comment: Can you please post related code

Comment: It is rather not a limitation, but a misunderstanding of how :not works.

Comment: Can you add minimum required HTML to reproduce the issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var act = $("ul.nav > li:not(div.modal ul.nav > li)");`

is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ue6jqp23/1/

Answer (score 1):

In javascript I think I'd approach it something like this:

**Identify selected tabs:**

```
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs li');

for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].classList.add('selected-tab');
    var tabAncestor = tabs[i].parentNode;

    while (tabAncestor.nodeName !== 'BODY') {
        if (tabAncestor.classList.contains('modal')) {
            tabs[i].classList.remove('selected-tab');
        }
        tabAncestor = tabAncestor.parentNode;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply collect the `Node List` with:

```
var selectedTabs = document.getElementsByClassName('selected-tab');
```

**Example:**

```js
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs li');

for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].classList.add('selected-tab');
    var tabAncestor = tabs[i].parentNode;

    while (tabAncestor.nodeName !== 'BODY') {
        if (tabAncestor.classList.contains('modal')) {
            tabs[i].classList.remove('selected-tab');
        }
        tabAncestor = tabAncestor.parentNode;
    }
}
```

```css
.selected-tab a, span {
color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <p>The tabs with <em>.selected-tab</em> class are indicated in <span>red</span>.</p>
        <!--  More nested on actual code-->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="modal fade lookup" id="search-adjustment-report-header-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```